# Prove that $(-\infty, b)$ for any $b \in \mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $c$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove that $(-\infty, b)$ for any $b \in \mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $c$

Proof: Define function $f: (-\infty, b) \rightarrow (-b, \infty)$ by $f(x) = -x$. Note that $f$ is one-to-one and onto because the equation can be solved uniquely for $x$. $x=-y$ is the only solution. Hence $\overline{\overline {(-\infty, b)}} = \overline{\overline{(-b, \infty)}} = \overline{\overline{(0, 1)}} = c$

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Is $\overline{\overline{(-b,\infty)}}=\overline{\overline{(0, 1)}}$ a know result?

Comment: Another approach is to directly find a bijection $(-\infty,b) \overset\sim\to (0,1)$.  One way to do this is to use the function $x \mapsto \frac1{b+1-x}$.